# What is an absolute and relative URL in laymans terms?

Tags: url

I was wondering what is an absolute and a relative URL in laymans terms?

Comment: It's explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Absolute_vs_relative_URLs).

Answer (score 0):

An absolute URL has the protocol, host, etc, such as...

```
https://example:8080/path?a=b#fragment
```

A relative URL omits the protocol, host, port, username, password, etc, and it will be resolved to an absolute URL generally by the context it is in...

```
path?a=b#fragment
```

If this relative URL was included on `http://example.com/abc`, it would point to `http://example.com/abc/path?a=b#fragment`.

You can read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) for more in depth knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are nothing paths to a resource at a remote location. Just as you can say the path to location in the real-world in the absolute sense as "10 Downing Street" vs in a relative sense like "turn left from the fountain and cross the road" so is the case in the internet.

Absolution path goes like:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618313`

Relative path can be used by something programs in relation to particular target.
For e.g. teh relative path of `/question/5618313` w.r.t `http://stackoverflow.com` can still make one end up in this question.

Answer (score 0):

An absolute URL is like a full address for a house, e.g.

```
123 Smith St,
Newport Beach
CA, USA, 123456
```

This is an absolute address because it identifies a house fully and independent of your current location.

A relatively URL is like a direction to a house relative to some fixed point. For example, suppose you you asked for directions at a service station, you might get:

```
Drive North, take the second right, 3rd house on the left
```

This is a relative address, because it is relative to where you are.